# Fixing damaged hard drive after OSX update

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility

I recently tried updating my Macbook Pro Retina to OSX El Capitan, however believing this to be a simple routine update, I did not backup my computer. Of course, the update was unsuccessful, somehow damaging my OSX partition and rendering it unbootable. I tried booting into my Recovery partition and then reinstalling OSX from there, but this did nothing. I also tried using First Aid on my partition (from disk utility) only to be met with the error:

> Invalid extent entry and incorrect number of file hard links

Its clear that my OSX volume is damaged, but my bootcamp windows partition works fine. Now, I have a ton of important files on my drive so a clean install is my last resort. I tried finding a bootable Diskwarrior USB file to try and fix my drive, but I couldn't find one which could be set up on windows. Furthermore, now my "Macintosh HD" partition doesn't even show up on the boot menu.

Right now, I only have access to my old pc, and my damaged mac. Is there any way I can fix this? At this point Im very desperate.

Comment: Upgrading is never "rather simple". Have you tried booting into Recovery HD or Internet Recovery? As a last resort,  (before erasing), Do you have any friends with Macs?

Comment: @IronCraftMan yes I have done both, neither of which have helped. I probably could borrow a Mac from one of my friends if firewire is the only option

Comment: why didn't they help? Could you verify/repair the disk?

Comment: @IronCraftMan this issue just happened today and I haven't had a chance to ask. All of my disk repairs failed